# Swift FPS drops when simply tapping

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, frame-rate

After updating Xcode to 8.3 and Swift to 3.1 I noticed a significant fps drops(sometimes even to 1-2) after doing any simple actions in app - and actually tapping and swiping. It also happens if touchBegan func and any gestureRecognisers are completely deleted from code. Moreover, it happens in the xcode's example code as well (when you create a game in swift 3.0 and above it has example of simple game - when tapping colorful circles appear).

Actual working app(game) without touches has stable 25% CPU usage and 60 fps. By single tap fps falls by 5-10, and CPU usage increases by 5%. After a bunch of taps, any multiple tapping makes the app dead - CPU 100% and 3-5 fps.(multiple - I mean quickly tapping without stop, sorry for my language)

Don't know whether it's a bug or nor. It happens in both simulator and real device (iphone 6s). My configuration is Macbook Air 2014 with 1.4GHz dual-core Intel Core i5. Xcode is the latest version by 25.04.2017

Thanks)

Comment: What frameworks are you using? Sprite Kit, Cocos2D, Unity, etc?

Comment: 1. Try to pause / add break point to see the treads running while tapping. See if some code runs on the main thread which causes the FPS to drop. 2. Try and comment out sections and see if FPS improves. By doing this you would slowly start to eliminate possibilities. At one point the FPS would improve. Then you can detect the code that causes the FPS to drop.

Comment: @Holly it's Sprite Kit

Comment: @user1046037 thanks, I'll try it. But by now it looks like even a project with no code at all in it except basic functions has FPS drops then tapping

Comment: Create a new project and create the function for tapping and paste it so that we could try it